# Java unable to load Tesseract library macOS

Tags: java, macos, homebrew, tesseract

I have installed Tesseract library with `brew install tesseract`. I ab able to run tesseract commands via terminal without any issue but when java application is started it throws an exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'tesseract':
dlopen(libtesseract.dylib, 0x0009): tried: '/Users/USERNAME/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-17.0.5/Contents/Home/bin/./libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/USERNAME/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-17.0.5/Contents/Home/bin/../lib/libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), 'libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Projects/Twitter Bot Detector/libtesseract.dylib' (no such file)
dlopen(libtesseract.dylib, 0x0009): tried: '/Users/USERNAME/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-17.0.5/Contents/Home/bin/./libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/USERNAME/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-17.0.5/Contents/Home/bin/../lib/libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), 'libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Projects/Twitter Bot Detector/libtesseract.dylib' (no such file)
```

Also I checked and the path for libtesseract.dylib is  `/usr/local/lib/libtesseract.dylib` which is not tried by dlopen command. `MacOS Monterey 12.6`

Can you show me a way to solve this?

Comment: How do you start the java app?

Comment: Most likely you need to have the dynamic library available on the classpath. If the piece of code loading the lib uses JNA, you may also have to cater to the architecture. Try placing a copy of it in `src/main/resources/darwin-x86-64` of your project, assuming you run an Intel mac.

Comment: @BrunoGrieder   Not the *classpath* but `java.library.path`

Comment: Yes, right to be exact with JNA: it is `jna.library.path` first. Full details here: https://www.javadoc.io/static/net.java.dev.jna/jna/5.12.1/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html

Comment: Possibly no JNA involved, else 'Frameworks' might appear among the search paths

Comment: Yes, it works if I set`System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "/usr/local/lib/libtesseract.dylib");`

Comment: Interesting. That's good, but actually that's *not* a path as such - it's a file

Comment: You are right, after that I got no input file exception. I removed the dylib file from the path and leave the folder only.